# What is the way to use MutationObserverInit with the Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, html, google-closure-compiler, mutation-observers

On the Mozilla Developer Network, there is an example on [how to use a MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage).

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

The `config` variable is an `Object`. But the closure compiler would get angry and

> ERROR - actual parameter 2 of MutationObserver.prototype.observe does not match formal parameter
>   found   : {attributes: boolean, characterData: boolean, childList: boolean}
>   required: (MutationObserverInit|null|undefined)
>     observer.observe(node, config);

As it is set in the [externs/html5.js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/html5.js#L2813).
*However*, I cannot find a way to instantiate a MutationObserverInit typed object because 'Uncaught ReferenceError: MutationObserverInit is not defined'.

What is the right thing to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the extern file is wrong and should be fixed.

This is work around:

```
var config = /** @type {MutationObserverInit} */ ({ attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });
```